# C++ Array vs Vector Sorting (vector ~2.5x slower than array in my case (No Optimization))

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I am doing an insertion sort on of `100000` elements. I have written two functions.

1- It is in which I copy the vector given to sort into an array then I apply sort and then I copy the array back to a vector for return.

2- It is in which I apply the sort on the given vector and then returns it.

Now according to my knowledge vectors are also dynamically created an array and the difference of C++ `Vector []` operator speed should be nonexistent or atleast not this much. So the method `2` should be faster than method `1`. But to my surprise It is opposite. I am trying to find a concrete answer rather than just array is faster. :)

Compiler version => gcc version 6.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
g++ main.cpp -o main

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<long> InsertionSort1(vector<long> nums){
    int vsize = nums.size();
    long* arr = new long[vsize];
    int swap, j;

    // Coping the vector to an array
    for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++){
        arr[i] = nums[i];
    }

    //sorting
    for(int i=1;i<vsize;i++){
        swap = arr[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && arr[j] > swap){
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--; 
        }

        arr[j+1] = swap;   

    }

    // Coping the array back to vector
    for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++){
        nums[i] = arr[i];
    }

    return nums;
}

vector<long> InsertionSort2(vector<long> nums){
    int vsize = nums.size();
    int swap, j;

    for(int i=1;i<vsize;i++){
        swap = nums[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && nums[j] > swap){
            nums[j+1] = nums[j];
            j--; 
        }

        nums[j+1] = swap;   

    }

    return nums;
}

int main(){

    vector<long> entries;
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        entries.push_back(rand()%100000);
    }

    double start = time(0);
    InsertionSort1(entries);
    double end = time(0);

    cout<<"With Array => "<<end-start<<endl;

    start = time(0);
    InsertionSort2(entries);
    end = time(0);

    cout<<"With Vector => "<<end-start<<endl;
}
```

The result of above Code is:

```
With Array 100000 => 8
With Vector 100000 => 19
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated: Did you forget to *seed* `rand()`?

Comment: Note that the usual resolution with `time` is in *seconds*, which means it's not very accurate. Either use [`std::clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) or better yet [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

Comment: It would also help if you told us the *results* of your tests. And also always do your tests *multiple time* to get an average, and always build with *optimizations enabled*.

Comment: i don't need to seed rand() since same values are used for both cases

Comment: will add results in few minutes

Comment: seed it for the very first time at least?

Comment: You will see speed up if you pass the vector in the functions by reference, i.e. `vector<long> &nums` or `const vector<long> &nums`

Comment: Also, with optimization enabled, take a look at the generated code. Modern compilers are very good at analyzing code and finding code that may not be used, leading to removal of statements, loop and perhaps even functions calls.

Comment: I'm wondering if there a validation check on the indexing used for a vector, although I thought this would only be done with a debug build, not a release build.

Comment: I k ow vector is passed by value but again

Comment: It is passed by value in both func

Comment: `long* arr = new long[vsize];` and copying num ... you'd get the exactly same thing with `long* arr = num.data();` without having to copy. Also such a function would normally take a pair of iterators and the same implementation used for arrays and vectors alike.

Comment: Optimizers are quite smart, but sometimes they may not understand the context fully; it _is_ possible that you may need to take a pointer to the first element (no need to copy anything!) and use it instead of `operator[]` to avoid continuous reloading of the data pointer from the vector members (if the compiler thinks the vector could be reallocated in the meanwhile). That being said, this shouldn't be the case here, as it's a local vector, and no external calls are made, so the compiler should clearly see that there's no possibility of reallocation.

Comment: Can't reproduce with visual studio with an optimised build. which compiler are you using? are you using an optimised build? As you are using `time()` and getting meaningful results I assume you are using a debug build as both methods take around second for me and therefore return a time of "1". In debug builds `operator []` will involve a function call and it is not surprising that it will be slow.

Comment: Put your build command line and/or compiler configuration, including optimization settings, [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52511045/edit). and out of curiosity, what is your timing when using [a *slightly* different insertion sort](https://pastebin.com/FHDu4nfz) (by slightly, I mean about 90% shorter)

Comment: @AlanBirtles
I am a student so i cant exactly understand what you mean by optimized build or debug build. I am using gcc version 6.2.0.

Comment: Look at your build command line. Something to the effect of `gcc --std=c11 -o main -O2 main.cpp`. That information belongs *in your question*.

Comment: Well, thanks for the update; I guess that's something. Telling us the compiler version is nice and all, but it *isn't* a build command line, and doesn't tell us what we've been asking for. When you're sitting at a shell prompt and you type `gcc....` to build your program. *what do you type* ? That belongs in your question. If it doesn't contain an optimization switch ( `-On` , where `n` is a number from 1..3), then you're performance testing non-optimized code, which is a monumental waste of time.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am sorry but i did not used optimized switch i am new to programing i came across this result while doing my assignment so wanted to know about it

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good thing to measure performance!  `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` or `google benchmark` are better suited tools for the job.

You need to enable a proper optimisation level, say `-O3` in order to have meaningful results.

Why do you like to implement a sorting algorithm. I compared your approch with `std::sort`? For academic purposes this is fine, otherwise you need to have a good reason and a measured proof, that you did a better job.

> With Array => 2.55608
>
> With Vector => 1.74857
>
> With std::sort => 0.00657156

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<long> InsertionSort1(vector<long> nums){
    int vsize = nums.size();
    long* arr = new long[vsize];
    int swap, j;

    // Coping the vector to an array
    for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++){
        arr[i] = nums[i];
    }

    //sorting
    for(int i=1;i<vsize;i++){
        swap = arr[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && arr[j] > swap){
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--; 
        }

        arr[j+1] = swap;   

    }

    // Coping the array back to vector
    for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++){
        nums[i] = arr[i];
    }
    // delete of is missing arr;
    return nums;
}

vector<long> InsertionSort2(vector<long> nums){
    int vsize = nums.size();
    int swap, j;

    for(int i=1;i<vsize;i++){
        swap = nums[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && nums[j] > swap){
            nums[j+1] = nums[j];
            j--; 
        }

        nums[j+1] = swap;   

    }

    return nums;
}

int main(){

    vector<long> entries;
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        entries.push_back(rand()%100000);
    }

    double start = time(0);
    InsertionSort1(entries);
    double end = time(0);

    cout<<"With Array => "<<end-start<<endl;

    start = time(0);
    InsertionSort2(entries);
    end = time(0);

    cout<<"With Vector => "<<end-start<<endl;
}
```

Comment: And the memory leak? Also, there is *zero* reason to create a manually-allocated sequence. The `nums` argument is pass by value. You already have a copy; just sort it. Coupled with using `std::sort` this entire function boils down to two lines, including `return nums;`.

Comment: I am not sure how is possible (vector being faster) i have executed my code on multiple machine and vector is always slower. (By multiple i mean at least 20)

Comment: Have you turned on optimization? -O3 compile option?

Comment: I am doing this for academic purposes. I came across this phenomena and i just want to know it's reason.

Comment: I my measurement it is slower as it should be.

Comment: I wasn't using any Optimization flag (sorry for wasting your time) 
but please tell me if the flag is non existent (not -O0) does compiler not do any optimization at all?

Comment: @drainzerrr Looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html : *"-O0 Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results. This is the default. "*